# NSString fill with labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, nsstring, format

So I am trying to fill a NSString with a few values from my other labels. For example the way I would do this with a NSLog is:

```
NSLog(@"%@ Score! %@-%@", homeTeam.text, homeScore.text, awayScore.text);
```

I created my string:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *homePushString;
```

(of course I synthesized it)

but I can not get the string to set correctly. Here is what I tried:

```
 self.homePushString = @"%@ Score! %@-%@", homeTeam.text, homeScore.text, awayScore.text;
```

Why does this not work? Thanks!

Comment: String formatting is **not a language feature.** It is a **library** feature. You can't just hammer format strings and varargs into arbitrary code -- Objective-C has no string interpolation (fortunately).

Comment: You're doing a bunch of things wrong here. First of all, a string can't be an IBOutlet, so the string property should be declared strong and without the IBOutlet qualifier. There's no need to use @synthsize any more, and the last line needs to be done like gabbler's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.homePushString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Score! %@-%@",homeTeam.text, homeScore.text, awayScore.text];
```